# Fill cell based on another sheets value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a spreadsheet on Google sheets with 2 sheets, `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`. On Sheet1 I have 2 columns (`ID1` and `Result1`), in which are filled. On Sheet2 I have 2 columns (`ID2` and `Result2`), in which ID2 is filled and Result2 is filled with the word "empty".

Sheet1 in my real spreadsheet is getting data from Google Forms, so every time Sheet1 receives a value on ID1 and Result1, it should search for the ID1 value on Sheet2's ID2 and when finding, paste Result1 value in Result2 in the row it's was found.

Result2 would then only be updated when there's new data on Sheet1 submitted from the form.

I created this editable form and spreadsheet to make it easier to understand (I also added a note explaining it in there). You can see the form [here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1ebBP9gYagmHJUBA3VEwKvggUcqRpYmaCc2oxELijbMc/edit) and the spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XKYfe8JQmJRw2OxK17svyH5o1J877WasudSUECspXGE).

Comment: After lengthy discussions, I think you "forgot" to mention that you do not want to use a formula on your `Sheet2` to return the matched result, but rather, hypothetically, there will be an event that will trigger the look up process and fill your `Sheet2` with results from `Sheet1` automatically. If that's the case you are after **Google Sheets Macros** (or `vba` in excel). The logic is to identify the triggering event, specify how and where to overwrite the values on your `Sheet2`. If so, you may want to add `#google-sheets-macros` to the tags of this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the current answers and comments I think I understand what you are looking for.

#### Answer:

*You can do this in Google Apps Script by creating a function that is bound to your Google Form which collects the latest response and does the data processing, and making it run on Form submission.*

#### Steps to take:

Firstly, on your Form, you will need to create a bound script. From the menu in the top right of the Form edit page, click `⋮ > Script editor`, which will open a new script page.

From there you can make a script which will automatically do this for you, and make an Installable Trigger which runs when you need.

#### Code:

After opening the Script Editor, you will see a ready-to-edit function that looks like this:

```js
function myFunction() {

}
```

Replace the entire script with the following code:

```js
function onSubmit(e) {
  var responses = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses();
  var response = responses[responses.length - 1].getItemResponses();
  var connectedSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('<your-sheet-id>').getSheets();
  var sheet2 = connectedSheet[1];  
  var result2Column = sheet2.getRange('A1:A').getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < result2Column.length; i++) {
    if (response[1] == result2Column[0]) {
      sheet2.getRange('B' + (i +1)).setValue(response[0]);
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure to replace `<your-sheet-id>` with the unique ID of your Google Sheeet - you can find this in the URL of the sheet between the `d/` and `/edit` like so:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<your-sheet-id>/edit
```

Run the script by pressing the play button (►) and authorise the application to run.

Then go to `Edit -> Current Project's Triggers` and set up a new installable trigger with the following settings:

- Choose which function to run: `onSubmit`
- Choose which deployment should run: `Head`
- Select event source: `From form`
- Select event type `On form submit`

#### Explanation:

This script will run each time a new form submission is made automatically - it will take the ID from the form response and search Sheet2 for it. If it's found, then the response given for result will be put in Sheet2 also, next to the corresponding ID.

#### References:

- [Google Apps Script Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Answer (score 1):

In cell `B2` of your second sheet I entered the following:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

[image: Results]

I guess **VLOOKUP** on Google-Sheets does allow reference across worksheets?

> FYI, when entering the formula, after enter the first argument which is your look up criteria, you can click your sheet1 and highlight column A and B, then go back to your sheet2 (with the second argument automatically filled by the system) to finish the formula with the third (result range column position within the look up range) and fourth argument (`TRUE` for approximate match and `FALSE` for exact match) and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit the formula.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't explained it right. Sheet1 in my real spreadsheet is getting data from Google Forms, so every time Sheet1 receives a value on ID1 and Result1, it should search for the ID1 value on Sheet2's ID2 and when finding, paste Result1 value in Result2 in the row it's was found.

Comment: @Luiz regardless how your data is updated on Sheet1, you can always look up `ID2` from your Sheet1 using **VLOOKUP** to return the corresponding result. I am not sure what is the real problem here?

Comment: It's updated with a form. Also I forgot to mention that result2 isn't actually empty, it has a value (in this case, say "empty"), so I couldn't have a formula there instead, it would only be updated when there's a new data on Sheet1 from the form.

Comment: @Luiz how about replace the hard-coded value in `Result2` with this formula `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE),"empty")` so if there is no match, `Result2` will show `empty`, otherwise it will return the most current result from your `Sheet1` regardless when your Sheet1 is updated.

Comment: But this way it won't be editable. For example, if we submit ID1 as 400 and Result1 as result100, it would look for 400 in ID2 and paste result100 in Result2 in the same row where the ID matched, but when someone try to edit result100 back to "empty", it'll get an error :(

Comment: @Luiz if you change the `result100` for ID `400` on your `Sheet1` to **empty**, I am pretty sure on your `Sheet2` the result for ID `400` will be showing **empty** as being returned by the **VLOOKUP** function. If you delete ID `400` on your `Sheet1`, **VLOOKUP** will display an error as no matching result can be found, that's why I suggested you to use **IFERROR** (on top of VLOOKUP) to return `empty` (or anything you like) to replace the error result.

Comment: But I need to change the `result100` to `empty` in Sheet2, that's the big problem :(

Comment: @Luiz so you mean even if there is a match on `Sheet1`, in some occasion you still need to overwrite the matched result on `Sheet2` to `empty`? There are ways to achieve that and I think @player0 has given you one example using `check box`.

Answer (score 0):

do it simply like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Sheet1!A:B, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]

---

or reset by checkbox:

[image: 0]

Comment: I'm really sorry! As I explained to Terry above, in my real spreadsheet Sheet1 is getting data from Google Forms, so every time Sheet1 receives a value on ID1 and Result1, it should search for the ID1 value on Sheet2's ID2 and when finding, paste Result1 value in Result2 in the row it's was found.

Comment: can you provide example of desired output in your sheet?

Comment: I updated the question with a new spreadsheet and form, so it's much more like to the real one.

Comment: @Luiz see your sheets

Comment: For example, in this form if we submit ID1 as 400 and Result1 as result100, it would look for 400 in ID2 and paste result100 in Result2 in the same row where the ID matched.

Comment: well, thats kinda exactly whats happening with suggested formula

Comment: It can't have a formula on the cell because the cells needs to be editable. If I write anything in it, it gives me an error.

Comment: For example, after the example above when Result2 has result100 as value, someone will manually edit it to "empty" again. If I do it now it'll get me an error.